# Visio Addin Where / When to Register WindowTurnedToPage

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsto, add-in, visio

I am developing a C# VSTO Visio Addin. In the addin I want to detect and trigger a page turned event handler when the user selects a different page in a given document. I have seen the following thread concerning registering the event:

[Catch WindowTurnedToPage Event in a Visio AddIn project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49439942/catch-windowturnedtopage-event-in-a-visio-addin-project?rq=1)

Copying this logic I have tried the following in ThisAddIn.cs:

```
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.ActiveWindow.WindowTurnedToPage += new Visio.EWindow_WindowTurnedToPageEventHandler( Window_WindowTurnedToPage);
    }

     public void Window_WindowTurnedToPage(Visio.Window Window)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Window changed to {0}", Window.Application.ActivePage.Name ));
    }
```

However, when I try and register the event handler as part in the call to ThisAddin_Startup I get a NPE because the "ActiveWindow" has not been set. It seems that there is a timing issue between registering the event handler and a Document / ActivePage being registered.

In summary I want my Visio Adddin to detect and respond to the user event when the active page in the loaded document changes.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks and regards,
Andrew

Comment: If the user stays on the backstage etc pages then it could be quite a while until an ActiveWindow is valid. How about putting the event handler additon inside a try ...catch, on exception set a timer for, say, 5 seconds and then try again. Repeat until success.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that registering a "document opened handler" first achieves the outcome that I was looking for.

```
        private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {

          ThisAddIn addin = ThisAddIn.getInstance();

          if (addin != null )
          {
            addin.Application.DocumentOpened += Application_DocumentOpened;
          }
      }

    private void Application_DocumentOpened(Visio.Document doc)
    {
        if (doc.Application != null)
        {
            Visio.EApplication_WindowTurnedToPageEventHandler appHandler = new Visio.EApplication_WindowTurnedToPageEventHandler(Application_WindowTurnedToPage);
            doc.Application.WindowTurnedToPage += appHandler;
        }
    }
```

So when a document is opened the window turned to page event handler is registered. However, I had to make the ThisAddIn class a singelton to get a handle to the Application instance to register the document opened handler. Not sure whether there are unintended side-effects.